# MATLAB: Efficient way to find the feasible region of first-order polynomials x, y with unknown coefficents in [-1, 1]

Tags: algorithm, matlab, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

As in the title, in MATLAB, I need the feasible region (bounds of all feasible solutions) of

```
x_0 + x_1 e_1 + ... + x_n e_n
```

and

```
y_0 + y_1 e_1 + ... + y_n e_n
```

where all unknown `e_i` are in the interval `[-1, 1]`. I would prefer the solution to not depend on non-standard 3rd party functions.

Below is my quick-and-dirty attempt, but the complexity grows O(2^n), where n is the number of `e_i`. Any thoughts?

```
x0 = 3;
x = [1; -3; 0];
y0 = -1;
y = [3; -2; 4];

% Get all permutations of noise symbol extremities
terms = size(x, 1);
xx = zeros(2^terms, 1);
yy = zeros(2^terms, 1);
for j = 1:2^terms
    e = double(bitget(j - 1, 1:terms))';
    e(e == 0) = -1;
    xx(j) = x0 + sum(x .* e);
    yy(j) = y0 + sum(y .* e);
end

k = convhull(xx, yy);
plot(xx(k), yy(k));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
% First generate all possible permutations for [-1, 1] for n terms. This is similar to what you have done but uses a matlab function
all_e = de2bi(0:(2^terms-1), terms).';
all_e(all_e == 0) = -1;
% Multiply corresponding values of x and y with those of e
xx = x0 + arrayfun(@(z) sum(x .* all_e(:, z)), 1:(2^terms));
yy = x0 + arrayfun(@(z) sum(y .* all_e(:, z)), 1:(2^terms));
```

You can read more about the function `de2bi` [here](https://in.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/de2bi.html)

A method to find the absolute minimum and maximum bounds is as follows:

```
max_e = double(x >= 0);
min_e = double(~max_e);
max_e(max_e == 0) = -1;
min_e(min_e == 0) = -1;
absMax = x0 + sum(x .* max_e);
absMin = x0 + sum(x .* min_e);
```

Similarly you could do for y

Comment: Thanks ammportal. I gave this a go just now, and get a bit of a speedup, but I still have problems with large n as the runtime complexity is still O(2^n). In addition, when pre-allocating like this, I now also have a large O(2^n) memory complexity! In practice, n is typically ~100, so you can imagine how much of a problem this causes. Do you know of any, for example, linear optimisation routines that do things a little less brute force and more analytically? Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure about all values, but there is a way to find the absolute maxima and minima easily. I will add it to my answer.

Comment: Another optimization I can think of is to not generate e_i's for 0 coefficients. this will reduce n by the number of 0 terms.